# What does this ip linux command mean?

Tags: linux

```
ip link add link eth2 dev col0000000000a7 type macvlan mode bridge
```

I can't find this usage in the manual.
Is it a combination of two commands?

Comment: It is a good question, but it is posted to the wrong site. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Yes it is adding a bridge device. See `man 8 ip` (and related "See Also" pages)

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-ip-command-examples-usage-syntax/) for details

> The ip command is used to assign an address to a network interface and/or configure network interface parameters on Linux operating systems. This command replaces old good and now deprecated ifconfig command on modern Linux distributions.

Looks like it is adding a bridging device to interface `eth2`.

Run `$ ip a show eth2` would give you more info on that particular interface.